# Variables show no value in debugger mouse over in Chrome version 79.0.3945.88

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, mousehover, javascript-debugger

The last updates of chrome stop showing the values of the variables on debugger mode when mouse over. The only access to the values is on the Scope and Watch tabs at the right bar.

I saw in other topics that this issue was resolved in old versions, but seems it came back in this version.

Why is not showing the value on mouse over anymore?

Comment: Are you on MAC?

Comment: No, i'm using Windows 10

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why is not showing the value on mouse over anymore?

Answer (score 0):

There is already an issue opened in the Google Chrome community website: [Chrome community post](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/22882968?msgid=22882968). Looks like it is simply a Chrome bug and there's nothing we can do about it.

It has almost 1000 upvotes and 218 replies in 3 days. Hopefully the Chrome team is aware and working on it. I would follow that post for further update.

**EDIT:** Fixed in chrome 80. Bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1033022

Comment: Nice, I will follow that issue.

Comment: @N.Troles it is now fixed in chrome 80.